# How to apply dark theme to this calendar view t?

Tags: 20.04

[image: Calendar view in ubuntu]

When I switched to dark mode appearance on ubuntu and for some reasons checked my calendar the dark theme was not there. I think it's a bug. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd install Tweaks and select another Shell Appearance. Yaru Dark should work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this will do!

Comment: Then you could accept the answer.